# MS Access vs MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

I run a website that uses a database, but not intensively, on a WAMP configuration. I currently use MS Access: We have a small database, < 4MB max, that can be downloaded for easy backup and emailed to organization members for completing tasks in the MS Access software (like generating reports, etc.). However, it requires MS Office software and isn't exactly standard use with PHP.

On the other hand, our host provides MySQL, which is typical with PHP, generally more powerful, has a greater availability of software and support, but backup can be a little messier.

But, MySQL is not hosted on the local host. So, I copied the information to MySQL, and made a copy of the site using the MySQL database. I proceeded to run some benchmarks, and surprisingly, MS Access was faster, marginally.

I am not sure which is the best direction to take at this point. Hoping the community can give some pros and cons that I haven't though about.

Comment: We're you running the MySQL server on the same hardware? How was the server configured? What other work was being done by the host? Without this information, benchmarks are meaningless.

Comment: Honestly, I can't answer much of that. I know what my host system is like, but the MySQL databases are hosted on a separate server and I do not know how it is configured or even running on without asking my host.

Comment: Understandable. I just wanted to suggest that you avoid jumping to conclusions about relative performance before knowing that information. Since the database is on a separate server running unknown hardware, that invalidates any performance measurements you've taken so far.

Comment: As long as the performance is reasonably the same, either would be fine. I was more concerned with capability and potential issues.

Comment: When properly configured, I would expect far better performance. Although given you have such a small database, performance probably isn't much of an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Access is way simpler, it's not surprising that rough benchmarking reveals it's faster. The difference comes when you have to deal with concurrent sessions and large data sets. Desktop apps are normally used by a single process at a time but in web applications concurrent queries are the norm.

Said that, if you've been using Access for a while and you didn't find issues, I don't think that switching to MySQL is going to make any difference regarding performance. I'd think about other considerations:

- Would you like to have Linux hosting as an option?
- Are you proficient enough with MySQL as to migrate code in a reasonable timespan and with reasonable quality?
- Can you replace those reports with plain HTML listings?

*BTW, MySQL backups can be automated with a simple command line script, it should not be messy at all.*

Comment: To your questions, Maybe, Yes, Yes. Migrating is near instant, as I have wrapped all DB code into a class with both Access and MySQL options. What I meant by messy as far as backups is (and my thought could be wrong): I have mostly seen them as text files with lines of sql that can re-create the database from scratch. Messier than 1 ready to go `.mdb` file.

Comment: I hadn't thought of concurrent queries. I have the DB options such that when the DB is open, that's it, meaning if something is inserted in the meantime, too bad until next connection, works OK for the web. But that could get messy if the site gets a ton of traffic.

Answer (score 1):

One pro that MS Access is already offering you is a client interface.  You've mentioned users that are "generating reports, etc.".  Unless you already have an alternative in place that will do everything they need, switching to MySQL will likely be a no-win situation.

Comment: You can use ODBC to import data into MS Access though. So users would still be able to generate reports using MS Access.

Comment: That is a nice feature. But, as the users start doing the same things, I make a page on the admin site to do the same thing so it is easier and more up to date. With MySQL, I would have to be more on top of this to support new needs.

Answer (score 0):

One big advantage of MySQL IMO is that PHP has [built in support](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) for MySQL. You can use ODBC with PHP to connect to MS Access but it's one more thing to set up and one more thing to 'break' at some point.

Could you set up MySQL on the host? Is it likely that your database would grow and become more complex in the near future?

Comment: Agreed. In fact, I thought of that before I made the site. I created a class to manage the database, with close on destruct, sql parsing, and exception handling. That, actually made it extremely easy to migrate to MySQL, I just changed a few functions in the class and viola!

Comment: PHP has no built in support for MySQL. It's an extension. Just like ODBC.

Comment: MySQL is already setup, just not on localhost, so there is a little network lag.

Comment: If PHP has built in MySQL support, then so does ODBC: http://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=odbc&lang=en&scope=quickref

Comment: ODBC requires you to setup a connection to SQL Server (the DSN). That's not the same as the native mysql functions built into PHP....

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick with Access database for such a small scale project! There's no need to move onto a bigger technology for the hell of it - put it this way, if you had 4 kids, and a bus came up for sale, would you buy the bus because you can fit your 4 kids in it?

Answer (score 0):

Access is ideal for us: several accountants using it in our accounting work in the same room but not through the internet, and none of us is programmer. The only thing to think about is the fee for Access copy-wright.

Mysql is free, yes, that is great, but Mysql lacks stored queries, forms and reports, and the quick "on_click, on_doubleclick..." functions  that are extremely useful and easy to handle in Access. Are there ways to solve this problem. Thank you.